# Item Highlighted Apple Menu Bar

Tags: keyboard, macos, high-sierra, menu-bar

I use `Control`+`F2` to highlight the menu bar pretty frequently.  How does the Menu Bar decide what menu to select in the list when a key is pressed?
Typically the character pressed on the keyboard is the first item in the list but after experimenting with this it seems inconsistent.

Sometimes pressing "H" will correspond to the to the first item in the drop down and other times the second.  Another example is selecting View in the menu.  Sometimes v will select View and other times Window.

[image]

Comment: @clemsamlang Please don't write answers in comments. It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments, as well as having other problems detailed on meta. Comments are for clarifying and improving the question; please don’t use them for other purposes. If you have an answer, write one using the answer section below.

Comment: Thanks @grg for clarifying your attitude about DOWN voting. I finally and irrevocably deleted my post as its "voting value" will stay at –3 so NOBODY will read it anyway. I was right with my observations, but some users simply didn't get it …

Comment: @clemsamlang Please don't assume people who criticize your post in comments will also downvote. There seem to be different behaviours for this functionality on different Macs, so let's work out the functional differences in more detail (which would probably help a lot of users) instead of attacking each other.

Comment: @clemsamlang Having said that, I actually liked your answer and would like to motivate you to repost it as a new answer. Maybe leave out the few lines which don't actually focus on the topic at hand, and state in which macOS version you have verified the behavior you describe.

Comment: William, which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @nohillside high Sierra currently.  My MacBook Pro 2011 can't go any father with out some trickery software wise which I haven't done.  I actually dual boot it with el captain because some software runs better that way.